# "Пикапмастер" или "пикап мастер"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется: *пикапмастер* или *пикап мастер*?

Comment: Это тот, кто ремонтирует пикапы?

Answer (score 2):

А есть такое слово? Может, просто - мастер пикапа.

Comment: Есть.Сленговое.Пишут по-разному.От английского Pickup Master.
Если даже его нет в словарях,то активное использование дает ему право на жизнь.Разве нет?

Comment: Активное употребление слова "ложить" вместо "класть" дает право спрашивать, как ставить ударение: "лОжить" или "ложИть"? И чем мастер пикапа хуже пикап-мастера? (Мне почему-то захотелось через дефис написать))).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь можно применить правило о правописании сложных слов, начинающихся с иноязычных элементов типа "авто-, мото-, био- и т.д. Как известно, такие слова пишутся слитно: автомастер, мотопробег, биостанция, пикапмастер.

Answer (score 0):

В английском языке встречаются следующие близкие по звучанию и значению термины:

pickup artist — опытный соблазнитель, мастер пикапа; рick-up line — набор шаблонов, ведущих к быстрому соблазнению (пикапу).

Согласно официальным правилам, нужно писать "пикап-мастер", это приложение к слову "мастер".

Однако в неофициальной литературе чаще встречается раздельное написание, что связано с влиянием подобных сочетаний в английском языке.

Сравнить: конференция онлайн, онлайн-конференция, а также: онлайн конференция  (неофиц.)